# Allow fun questions

Tags: discussion, off-topic, sources

Can we allow questions (with a disclaimer) that are not-serious, as in based on a fictional claim? To give concrete examples,

> J.K.Rowling claims in Harry Potter that if you jump into a fireplace, you can move to a different one if you say the new place before you go in. Does anyone have anecdotal evidence for this?

Or one from Lewis Carroll:

> Lewis Carroll claims in Through the Looking-Glass that if you go through a mirror, you will enter a world where animals speak. Is this true?

You would have to have a disclaimer that says something like, **"Don't take this claim or answers seriously."** We'd also have a separate tag (like "fun") so people could block such questions.

I don't know if this has been tried before, but I know something similar has been done on some other SE sites. I couldn't find anything related on meta, except perhaps [Should we allow the Santa question?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1290/should-we-allow-the-santa-question)

Comment: What's the similar thing you found on other SE sites?

Comment: @Articuno For example, http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-trolling/info and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purim-torah-in-jest with rules [here](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/purim-torah-policy-allowed-but-regulated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it may be fun, I don't think it serves the purposes of this site. I enjoy humor tremendously, but like most everything in life, it has its place.  I particularly enjoy going to skeptically themed comics when I want to cross the skepticism and humor streams.

Here is a small list that may help you:

[Carbon Dating](http://carbon-comic.com/)

[Ape, not Monkey](http://www.apenotmonkey.com/)

[Saturday Morning Breakfast Cereal](http://www.smbc-comics.com/)

[Treelobsters](http://www.treelobsters.com/)

[XKCD](http://xkcd.com/)

There are more, but these are my favorites.

Answer (score 0):

## “Stack Overflow: Where We Hate Fun”

[Read more](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/)

[image: We Hate Fun]

Answer (score 0):

I think [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/311/hub-of-reason) is the best place to ask about claims not based in reality.

[Meta-tagging is explicitly discouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Comment: That link gives two definitions for meta-tags, niether of which are applicable here. **If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.** and **If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag.**

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not explicitly familiar with the site, I think that the [Sci-Fi/Fantasy Site](http://scifi.stackexchange.com) would be a better home for these questions. If this is not the case however, you could always [Propose a new site on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com).